# Highlight color filtered items with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How I can highlight the content filtering ? I managed to filter content searched but I can not change the elements of color ...

This is my code:

```js
var BubbleChart, root,
  __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

BubbleChart = (function() {

  function BubbleChart(data) {
    this.do_filter = __bind(this.do_filter, this);

    this.use_filters = __bind(this.use_filters, this);

    this.hide_details = __bind(this.hide_details, this);

    this.show_details = __bind(this.show_details, this);

    this.hide_labels = __bind(this.hide_labels, this);

    this.display_labels = __bind(this.display_labels, this);

    this.move_towards_group = __bind(this.move_towards_group, this);

    this.display_by_group = __bind(this.display_by_group, this);

    this.move_towards_group_center = __bind(this.move_towards_group_center, this);

    this.group_by = __bind(this.group_by, this);

    this.get_distinct_values = __bind(this.get_distinct_values, this);

    this.color_by = __bind(this.color_by, this);

    this.remove_colors = __bind(this.remove_colors, this);

    this.sort = __bind(this.sort, this);

    this.get_color_map = __bind(this.get_color_map, this);

    this.get_color_map_lookup_set = __bind(this.get_color_map_lookup_set, this);

    this.get_color_map_achievement = __bind(this.get_color_map_achievement, this);

    this.move_towards_center = __bind(this.move_towards_center, this);

    this.display_group_all = __bind(this.display_group_all, this);

    // Agregado para BUSCAR
    this.updateSearch = __bind(this.updateSearch, this);

    this.start = __bind(this.start, this);

    this.create_vis = __bind(this.create_vis, this);

    this.create_nodes = __bind(this.create_nodes, this);
    this.data = data;

    this.width = 600;   /* for span10 of twitter bootstrap */
    this.height = 300;
    //this.tooltip = CustomTooltip("my_tooltip", 200);
    this.center = {
      x: this.width / 2,
      y: this.height / 2
    };
    this.layout_gravity = -0.01;
    // DISPERSION ENTRE NODOS
    this.damper = 0.6;
    this.vis = null;
    this.force = null;
    this.circles = null;
    this.nodes = [];
    this.currentCircles = [];

    var num_max_indicadores;
    num_max_indicadores = d3.max(this.data, function(d) {
      return parseInt(d.numIndicadores.substr(1));
    });

    // P E N D I E N T E
    this.radius_scale = d3.scale.pow().exponent(0.01).domain([1, 2]).range([20, 30]);

    this.create_nodes();
    this.create_vis();

    this.circles.style("fill",'#50852C');
  }

    var nodeColors;
    nodeColors = d3.scale.category20();


  BubbleChart.prototype.updateSearch = function(searchTerm) {
    var searchRegEx;
    var _this = this;
    element = d3.select(this);
    searchRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
    return this.data.forEach(function(d) {
      var element, match;
      match = d.Nombre.toLowerCase().search(searchRegEx);
      console.log(match);
      if (searchTerm.length > 0 && match >= 0) {
        //this.circles.style("fill",'#F20F0F');
        this.data.style("fill", "#FFFFF").style("stroke-width", 2.0).style("stroke", "#F20F0F");
        return d.searched = true;
      } else {
        d.searched = false;
      }
    });
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.buscar = function(filterText) {
    //filteredData = data;
    element = d3.select(this);
    console.log(element);
    filterText = filterText.toLowerCase();
    if (filterText !== ""){
      console.log("entro al IF");
      //this.circles.filter(function(d) { return d.Nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) === 0 }).style("fill",'#FFFFFF');
      var test = this.data.filter(function(d) { return d.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) === 0 });
      //element.style("fill", "#red").style("stroke-width", 2.0).style("stroke", "#555");
      console.log(test);
    }

    console.log("salio del IF");
  };


  BubbleChart.prototype.create_nodes = function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.data.forEach(function(d, i) {
      var node;
      var radius = _this.radius_scale(_this.getRadius(d));
      node = {
        id: i,
        original: d,
        radius:  radius,
        value: radius,
        x: Math.random() * _this.width,
        y: Math.random() * _this.height
      };
      _this.nodes.push(node);
    });

  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.create_vis = function() {
    var that,
      _this = this;
    this.vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg").attr("width", this.width).attr("height", this.height).attr("id", "svg_vis");
    this.circles = this.vis.selectAll("circle").data(this.nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });
    that = this;
    this.circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 100).style("fill", function(d) {
      return '#50852C';
    }).attr("stroke-width", 2).attr("stroke", function(d) {
      return '#404040';
    }).attr("id", function(d) {
      return "bubble_" + d.id;
    }).attr("opacity", 0).on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      return that.show_details(d, i, this);
    }).on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
      return that.hide_details(d, i, this);
    }).on("click", function(d, i) {
      return that.muestra_info(d, i, this);
    });
    this.circles.transition().duration(2000).attr("opacity", 1).attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.radius;
    });
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.charge = function(d) {
    if (d.radius === 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return -Math.pow(d.radius, 2);
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.start = function() {
    this.force = d3.layout.force().nodes(this.nodes).size([this.width, this.height]);
    return this.circles.call(this.force.drag);
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.display_group_all = function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.hide_labels();
    this.force.gravity(this.layout_gravity).charge(this.charge).friction(0.9).on("tick", function(e) {
      _this.circles.each(_this.move_towards_center(e.alpha)).attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      }).attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
    });
    this.force.start();
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.move_towards_center = function(alpha) {
    var _this = this;
    return function(d) {
      d.x = d.x + (_this.center.x - d.x) * (_this.damper + 0.02) * alpha;
      return d.y = d.y + (_this.center.y - d.y) * (_this.damper + 0.02) * alpha;
    };
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.get_color_map_lookup_set = function(allValuesArray) {
    var baseArray, color_map, index, value, _i, _len;
    baseArray = ["#0000D9", "#FF00FF", "#FF0033", "#FFCC66", "#66CC33", "#33FFCC", "#00A0AA", "#FFCCFF", "#FF9933", "#99FF99", "#00BB00", "#CCFFCC", "#333333", "#CCCCCC", "#99CCCC", "#FF0000"];
    index = 0;
    color_map = {};
    for (_i = 0, _len = allValuesArray.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      value = allValuesArray[_i];
      color_map[value] = baseArray[index];
      index = index + 1;
      if (index >= baseArray.length) {
        index = 0;
      }
    }
    return color_map;
  };


  BubbleChart.prototype.get_color_map = function(allValuesArray) {
    return this.get_color_map_lookup_set(allValuesArray);
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.sort = function(allValuesArray) {
    allValuesArray.sort();
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.remove_colors = function() {
    this.circles.transition().duration(2000).style("fill", "#50852C");
    hide_color_chart();
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.color_by = function(what_to_color_by) {
    var allValuesArray, color_mapper,
      _this = this;
    this.what_to_color_by = what_to_color_by;
    allValuesArray = this.get_distinct_values(what_to_color_by);
    color_mapper = this.get_color_map(allValuesArray);
    show_color_chart(what_to_color_by, color_mapper);
    this.circles.transition().duration(1000).style("fill", function(d) {
      return color_mapper[d.original[what_to_color_by]];
    });
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.get_distinct_values = function(what) {
    var allValues, allValuesArray, key, value,
      _this = this;
    allValues = {};
    this.nodes.forEach(function(d) {
      var value;
      value = d.original[what];
      var flag = false;
      var filterers = $('.filter_block input').filter(function() {
        return !this.checked;
      }).each(function () {
        if(value == this.value) {
          flag = true;
        }
      })

      if(!flag) {
          allValues[value] = true;
      }

    });
    allValuesArray = [];
    for (key in allValues) {
      value = allValues[key];
      allValuesArray.push(key);
    }
    this.sort(allValuesArray);
    return allValuesArray;
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.group_by = function(what_to_group_by) {
    var allValuesArray, numCenters, position, total_slots,
      _this = this;
    this.what_to_group_by = what_to_group_by;
    allValuesArray = this.get_distinct_values(what_to_group_by);
    numCenters = allValuesArray.length;
    this.group_centers = {};
    this.group_labels = {};
    position = 2;
    total_slots = allValuesArray.length + 3;
    allValuesArray.forEach(function(i) {
      var x_position;
      x_position = _this.width * position / total_slots;
      _this.group_centers[i] = {
        x: x_position,
        y: _this.height / 2
      };
      _this.group_labels[i] = x_position;
      position = position + 1;
    });
    this.hide_labels();

    this.force.gravity(this.layout_gravity).charge(this.charge).friction(0.9).on("tick", function(e) {
      _this.circles.each(_this.move_towards_group_center(e.alpha)).attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      }).attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
    });
    this.force.start();
    this.display_labels();
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.move_towards_group_center = function(alpha) {
    var _this = this;
    return function(d) {
      var target, value;
      value = d.original[_this.what_to_group_by];
      target = _this.group_centers[value];
      if(typeof target == 'undefined')return;
      d.x = d.x + (target.x - d.x) * (_this.damper + 0.02) * alpha * 1.1;
      d.y = d.y + (target.y - d.y) * (_this.damper + 0.02) * alpha * 1.1;
    };
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.move_towards_group = function(alpha) {
    var _this = this;
    return function(d) {
      var target;
      target = _this.group_centers[d.group];
      d.x = d.x + (target.x - d.x) * (_this.damper + 0.02) * alpha * 1.1;
      d.y = d.y + (target.y - d.y) * (_this.damper + 0.02) * alpha * 1.1;
    };
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.display_labels = function(filters) {
    var label_data, labels,
      _this = this;
    var group_labels = this.group_labels;
    console.log('etiquetas',group_labels);

    _this.hide_labels();
    label_data = d3.keys(group_labels);
    labels = this.vis.selectAll(".top_labels").data(label_data);

    labels.enter().append("text").attr("class", "top_labels").attr("x", function(d) {
      return group_labels[d];
    }).attr("y", 10).attr("text-anchor", "start").text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.hide_labels = function() {
    var labels;
    labels = this.vis.selectAll(".top_labels").remove();
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.show_details = function(data, i, element) {
    var content, key, title, value, _ref;
    d3.select(element).attr("stroke", "black");
    content = data.original.Nombre;
    //this.tooltip.showTooltip(content, d3.event);
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.hide_details = function(data, i, element) {
    d3.select(element).attr("stroke", "#404040");
    //this.tooltip.hideTooltip();
  };

   BubbleChart.prototype.muestra_info = function(data) {
    var content, title, value, _ref, encabezado, contenido;
    content = "";
    encabezado = "";
    contenido = "";
    _ref = data.original;
    for (key in _ref) {
      value = _ref[key];
      title = key.substring(key.indexOf(":") + 1);
      if (title === 'numIndicadores'){
        title = 'Número de Indicadores';
      }
      encabezado += "<th>" + title + "</th>";
      contenido += "<td>" + value + "</td>";
    }
    content += "<table class=\"table table-bordered\"><thead><tr>" + encabezado + "</tr></thead><tbody><tr>" + contenido + "</tr></tbody></table>";
    $("#info").empty();
    $("#info").append(content);
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.use_filters = function (filters,targets) {
    var filteredCircles = this.nodes.filter(function (d) {
      var original = d.original;
      var flag = true;
      d.radius = d.value;
      for(var i = 0,len = filters.length; i< len; i++) {
        if(original[targets[i]] === filters[i]) {
          d.radius = 0;
          flag = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      return flag;
    });

    this.do_filter();
    $('#group-everything-by').change();

  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.do_filter = function() {
    this.force.start();
    this.circles.transition().duration(2000).attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.radius
    });
  };

  BubbleChart.prototype.getRadius = function (node) {
    var r = 0;
    var aoi = node.numIndicadores;
      if( aoi !== '') {
        var suffix = aoi.substr(-1);   // getting K or M
        var a = aoi.substring(1, aoi.length-1);   // removing $ and K and M
        if(suffix == 'M') {

        }
        else if(suffix == 'K') {
          a /= 1;
        }
        r = aoi.substr();
        //r = a;
      }
    return r ;
  }

  return BubbleChart;

})();

root = typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null ? exports : this;

$(function() {
  var chart, render_chart, render_vis,
    _this = this;
  chart = null;
  render_vis = function(csv) {
    render_filters_colors_and_groups(csv);
    render_chart(csv);
  };
  render_chart = function(csv) {
    chart = new BubbleChart(csv);
    chart.start();
    root.display_all();
  };
  root.display_all = function() {
    chart.display_group_all();
    //chart.create_scale();
  };
  root.group_by = function(groupBy) {
    if (groupBy === '') {
      chart.display_group_all();
    } else {
      chart.group_by(groupBy);
    }
  };
  root.color_by = function(colorBy) {
    if (colorBy === '') {
      chart.remove_colors();
    } else {
      chart.color_by(colorBy);
    }
  };
  root.use_filters = function(filters,targets) {
    chart.use_filters(filters,targets);
  };

  root.display_labels = function(filters) {
    chart.display_labels(filters);
  };

  var bardata = "servicio,segmento,nombre,indicadores,unidad,numIndicadores\nC1,FFF,AAA,ccc,sss,1\nC2,XXXX,AAAA,gfgfgf,DGRIRST,6\nC3,YYYY,BBBB,gfgfgf,DGRIRST,4\nC1,ZZZ,CCCC,nnnn,DGRIRST,2";

  letters = d3.csv.parse(bardata);
  render_vis(letters);

  // Evento KEYUP para buscar
  $("#buscar").keyup(function() {
    var searchTerm;
    searchTerm = $(this).val();
    return chart.buscar(searchTerm);
  });
});


        var initialise_form = function (selectionOptions) {
            var filterers = $('.filter_block input');
            filterers.change(function() {
              var filters = [];
              var targets = [];
              filterers.filter(function () {
                return !this.checked
              }).each(function (k,v) {
                filters[k] = v.value;
                targets[k] = $(v).data('target');
              });

              use_filters(filters,targets);

            });

            var groupSelect = $('#group-everything-by');
            for (var opt in selectionOptions) {
                var lookup = selectionOptions[opt];
                groupSelect.append('<option value="' + lookup.key + '">' + lookup.title + '</option>');
            }
            var ResetGrouping = function () {
                var groupBy = groupSelect.val();
                group_by(groupBy);
            };

            groupSelect.change(ResetGrouping);

            var colorSelect = $('#color-everything-by');
            for (var opt in selectionOptions) {
                var lookup = selectionOptions[opt];
                colorSelect.append('<option value="' + lookup.key + '">' + lookup.title + '</option>');
            }
            var ResetColors = function () {
                var colorBy = colorSelect.val();
                color_by(colorBy);
            };

            $('#clear_filters').click(function () {
                if($(this).hasClass('select')) {
                  $('.filter_block input').attr('checked', 'checked');
                }
                else {
                  $('.filter_block input').prop('checked', false);
                }
                $(this).toggleClass('select clear');
                filterers.change();
                return false;
            });

            colorSelect.change(ResetColors);
        };

        function get_distinct_values(csv, keyType, key) {
            var allValues = {};
            for (var i in csv) {
                var value = csv[i][key];
                allValues[value] = true;
            }

            var allValuesArray = [];
            for (var i in allValues)
                allValuesArray.push(i);

            allValuesArray.sort();
            return allValuesArray
        }

        function keyToLookup(key) {
            var firstPartEnds = key.indexOf(':');
            if (firstPartEnds <= 0)
                return { key: key, type: key, title: key };

            var firstPart = key.substring(0, firstPartEnds);
            var secondPart = key.substring(firstPartEnds + 1);

            return { key: key, type: firstPart, title: secondPart };
        }
        function render_filters_colors_and_groups(csv) {
            var first = csv[0];

            var lookups = [];
            for (var key in first) {
                var lookup = keyToLookup(key);

                // SELECCIONA LOS CAMPOS A FILTRAR
                switch (lookup.type) {
                    case "segmento":
                    case "nombre":
                    lookups.push(lookup);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            var filterList = $('#filter-list');
            for (var i in lookups) {
                var lookup = lookups[i];
                console.log(lookup);
                var values = get_distinct_values(csv, lookup.type, lookup.key);
                var item = $('<li class="filter_block dropdown-header"><div class="filter_title"><b>' + lookup.title + '</b></div></li>');
                for (var j in values) {
                    var checkbox = $('<li><input data-target="' + lookup.key + '" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="' + values[j] + '"/> ' + values[j] + '</li>');
                    checkbox.appendTo(item);
                }
                item.appendTo(filterList);
            }
            initialise_form(lookups);
        }

        function hide_color_chart() {
            var colorbar = $('#color-hints');
            colorbar.fadeOut(500, function () {
                $(this).empty();
            });
        }
        function show_color_chart(what_to_color_by, color_mapper) {
            var colorbar = $('#color-hints');
            colorbar.fadeOut(500, function () {
                colorbar.empty();

                var lookup = keyToLookup(what_to_color_by);
                $('<h4>' + lookup.title + ':</h4>').appendTo(colorbar);

                var table = $('<table class="table" />');
                for (var key in color_mapper) {
                    var row = $('<tr/>');

                    var cell = $('<td/>');
                    var square = $('<div style="width: 15px; height: 15px; background: ' + color_mapper[key] + ';">&nbsp;</div>');
                    square.appendTo(cell);
                    cell.appendTo(row);

                    cell = $('<td/>');
                    cell.text(' ' + key + ' ');
                    cell.appendTo(row);
                    row.appendTo(table);
                }
                table.appendTo(colorbar);
                colorbar.fadeIn(500);
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <header>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    </header>
    <table>
      <td>
        <div id="vis"></div>
        <form id="search_form" action="#" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
          <label>Search:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buscar" value="" placeholder="Buscar elemento"/>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2>Group by:</h2>
        <select id='group-everything-by'>
          <option value=''>-- No group --</option>
        </select>
        <h2>Colour:</h2>
        <select id='color-everything-by'>
          <option value=''>-- No color --</option>
        </select>
        <h2>Filters:</h2>
        <div id="filter-list"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='color-hints'></div>
      </td>
    </table>
</body>
```

Add a link as an example of result desired "search": http://projects.flowingdata.com/tut/interactive_network_demo/

Comment: what is it youre trying to color ?

Comment: The objects that were leaked in the search.